# Offsetting Voltage from 2.5 V to 0 V without Effecting gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to digitize a Hall Sensor whose center voltage is 2.5V and the gain it's output is 1.5V to 3.5V, or ±1V. My digitizing card's center voltage is 0V and I would like to get the full range of the sensor in the 0V space, -1V to +1V.  I'm using a LM358 op amp to try to do the task.  I'm very new to building circuits and I really don't know where to start.

Comment: What supply rails are available from the digitizing card?

Comment: There are no voltages coming from the card at all.  It is only data in.  Here's the card: http://www.signatec.com/products/daq/high-speed-digitizer-board-px1500-2.html

Comment: I've been using USB to power the sensor and the amp, but I'm realizing that 5-0V isn't going to cut it.  I was thinking that I'd invert the +5V for input into the amplifier and still be able to use a common source to power both the sensor and the amplifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRo0Gx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that the op-amp requires +/- supplies. You can generate the negative supply from your +5V supply using an [ICL7660](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/charge-pumps/ICL7660.html) and a few ceramic or electrolytic capacitors. Not shown are supply bypass capacitors.

Comment: @ Spehro I like it.

Comment: @ Spehro I built the circuit and it worked great. I ended up using an ATX power supply for the  ±5V source.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to take in 1.5 to 3.5v, and output the same change in voltage but shifted down to swing +-1volt.

How about this [notice we don't need a calculator to design this]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzNYZX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I also built your circuit and it worked great.  Your explanation was very clear and I learned a lot from it.  Thank you.

Comment: I have another problem.  Both circuits worked as advertised, but I can only upvote one of the two.  Somehow that doesn't seem fair.  Thank you both again for helping me out.

Comment: @ bgeorge98121 Upvote Spehro answer. But before you upvote it, be sure you understand its elegance  What he did is useful in many situations.